# Deleting colums of dataFrame where row value is constant for all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting with a pandas DataFrame such as

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0, 3, 1.4, 3], [0, 3, 1.3, 1], [0, 3, 0.5, 3]]
)
```

or visually:

```
   0  1  2    3  
0[[0, 3, 1.4, 3] 
1 [0, 3, 1.3, 1]
1 [0, 3, 0.5, 3]]
```

and given a special value `x_1=3`

What would be a smart and scaling way to come up with a DataFrame that deletes all columns in df with a constant value x in EACH row?

The result in this example would be the dataFrame df without column 1.

df_altered =

```
   0  1    2 
0[[0, 1.4, 3] 
1 [0, 1.3, 1]
2 [0, 0.5, 3]]
```

In a small DataFrame I could itterate over all rows for each column but that would not scale and work with large DataFrames.

Comment: Your title does not match your description. Why isn't the 0 column also removed?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It seems he forgot to remove the zero column. It's a shame you deleted you answer, as I was curious about the solution.

Comment: He says in the question that given a special value: x=3, remove the columns that contain that value in all the rows. So the column with all 0 values should not be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.drop()`:

```
df.drop(columns=df.columns[(df == 3).all()])
```

Output:

```
    0   2   3
0   0   1.4 3
1   0   1.3 1
2   0   0.5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to determine the columns with equal values using:

```
>>> (df == df.iloc[0]).all(axis=0)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Then extract the inverse of the above mask:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, ~(df == df.iloc[0]).all(axis=0).to_numpy()]
     2  3
0  1.4  3
1  1.3  1
2  0.5  3
```

Comment: Your reply helped me to see that there was more to it than I first realized. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
## find the unique val in each column
no_unique_val = df.nunique()

val = 3
for column_name in no_unique_val.index:    
    if 1 == no_unique_val[column_name] and val == df[column_name].values[0]:            
        df.drop(column_name,axis=1, inplace=True)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and then [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) as boolean mask

```
df.loc[:, df.ne(3).any()]

   0    2  3
0  0  1.4  3
1  0  1.3  1
2  0  0.5  3
```